# Issues migrating VisualStateManager related code from .net 3.5 to .net 4

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, visualstatemanager

I have various custom behavior classes defined which derive themselves from ControlBehavior class. The ControlBehavior class is missing in .net 4.

ControlBehavior was part of [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) before it was released in .net 4.

So how to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure ControlBehavior is from the .NET Framework?  I can find no reference to it on MSDN.  It sounds like something that might have come from Expression Blend?  What is the assembly name and namespace of ControlBehavior?

Comment: question updated - ControlBehavior was part of WPF Toolkit before VSM was later release in .net 4

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to grab the source of the WPFToolkit and implement your own version of that (behavior) class.